# Anycable Websocket disconnects automatically while sending binary data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable, uint8array

I have an AnyCable/Actioncable running on a Rails 6 server, when trying to send binary (uint8Array) data over the websocket from browser to server the websocket connection will disconnect and reconnect automatically without any error (on both client and server) after sending the binary data and likely terminating the upload before it finishes.

The uint8array was a small jpg converted with FileReader() into a uint8array, Chrome dev tools says the size of the array was about 12mb.

I think the ping message received from the server every 3 seconds is interrupted by the data upload so the client tries to reset the  connection when it doesn't receive the ping message on time.

Is this accurate or could it be something else?

I'm using the actioncable NPM package in React to communicate over the socket, like so:

```
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event) {
  let arrayBuffer = this.result;
  let uint8Array  = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  console.log(uint8Array)
  socket.binaryType = "arraybuffer"
  socket.send(uint8Array);
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);

send(paste) {
  const pasteParams = {
  command: "message",
  action: "create",
  data: {
    content: paste,
    content_type: "arraybuffer",
    device: "nexus6p"
  }
};
this.consumer.send(pasteParams, { binary: true, mask: true });
```

}